# Does rails set anything in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Basically, if I have two rails applications, with different database.yml settings, both connecting to the same database, will they conflict with each other?

Or is database.yml specific to the local application?

Essentially, does rails create just a raw database connection like mysql workbench would? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If they connect to the same server but different databases then they shouldn't interfere.  If they attempt to connect to the same database and update the same tables, they may or may not conflict depending on how they use transactions.  You must provide much more detail for anyone to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .yml file is simplyba connection config for your app.  Its totally fine to connect to the same app with different .yml

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought.